# does php ternary operator only 'return' a true or false?

Tags: php, javascript

I have a php ternary operator as follows that does not work:

```
 var newLoginTxt = <?=$_SESSION['loginStatus']? 'Logged in' : 'Login'?>;
 alert("About to set the navbar's login text to: " + newLoginTxt);
```

No alert box appears at all.

However this does work:

```
var curLoginStatusSessionVar = <?=$_SESSION['loginStatus']? 'true' : 'false'?>;
alert("Testing: " + curLoginStatusSessionVar);
```

The alert box appears and says "Testing: false"

I have the following article seeming to say that the ternary operator in php CAN in fact return values other than 'true' or 'false':
http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators

Okay, even more odd -- in the code below, why does the first "Testing" alert box appear, then the 2nd "Testing" alert box NOT appear?  It's the exact same code:

```
      // THIS "Testing" ALERT BOX APPEARS FINE**
var curLoginStatusSessionVar = <?=$_SESSION['loginStatus']? 'true' : "false"?>;
alert("Testing: " + curLoginStatusSessionVar);


var newLoginTxt = <?=$_SESSION['loginStatus']? 'Logged in' : 'Login'?>;
alert("About to set the navbar's login text to: " + newLoginTxt);


    // THIS IDENTICAL "Testing" ALERT BOX NEVER APPEARS**
curLoginStatusSessionVar = <?=$_SESSION['loginStatus']? 'true' : 'false'?>;
alert("Testing" + curLoginStatusSessionVar);
```

Comment: Use client-side tools to look at the generated output and open a JS console and see what goes wrong. It's not going to be the ternary operator's fault.

Comment: your problem is not related to a ternary operator, you're not closing your strings correctly.Check out phihag's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is completely unrelated to the ternary expression: In JavaScript, like in modern php, **strings must be encapsulated by quotes**.

true and false happen to be JavaScript constants. Therefore, you want:

```
var newLoginTxt = "<?=$_SESSION['loginStatus']? 'Logged in' : 'Login'?>";
//                ^                                                    ^
```

Alternatively, and if the data is more complicated, use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/). For example, if you want to access the value of a php variable `$title` (which could contain quotes) in JavaScript:

```
<?php $title = '"Java"Script'; ?>
var title = <?php echo json_encode($title); ?>;
alert(title);
```

Comment: Thanks. That was the problem. Good eye!    I'm giving an up-arrow to everyone who caught this and I'm accepting this answer -- thanks folks.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you observe this behaviour is because you missed a set of quotes.

Do:

```
var newLoginTxt = "<?=$_SESSION['loginStatus']? 'Logged in' : 'Login'?>";
alert("About to set the navbar's login text to: " + newLoginTxt);
```

And it will work.

If you look at you original code, the output will be:

```
var newLoginTxt = Logged in; // Syntax error
// ...or...
var newLoginTxt = Login; // Used (probably) undefined variable
```

The reason you don't have this problem with the second example is the output will be:

```
var curLoginStatusSessionVar = true;
// ...or...
var curLoginStatusSessionVar = false;
```

...which as you can see, are both valid assignments of a boolean. When booleans are converted to strings in JS (for example, when you alert them) you will see the string `true` or `false`.

If you add the extra set of quotes, the output is now:

```
var newLoginTxt = "Logged in";
// ...or...
var newLoginTxt = "Login";
```

Which are both valid string assignments, so should fix the problem.

As a side note, you should for the moment avoid using the `<?=` shorthand PHP tag. This is because (before PHP 5.4) the use of this syntax requires `short_open_tag` to be enabled, which it is not in many environments, such as most shared hosts. Until PHP 5.4 is more widely available, for portability reasons you should stick to the full `<?php` tag at all times. So your line would actually be:

```
var newLoginTxt = "<?php echo $_SESSION['loginStatus'] ? 'Logged in' : 'Login' ?>";
```

Comment: Dave thanks MIGHTILY for the gotcha on the <?= syntax!  I'm going with <?php echo  for now -- thanks also for your excellent explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This may not solve your problem but you should ensure the $_SESSION variable you're operating on exists like so:

```
empty($_SESSION['loginStatus']) ? "false" : "true"
```

This way, if `$_SESSION['loginStatus']` doesn't exist the code still works.

Also, the ternary operation can return anything you want ... it's not restricted to TRUE/FALSE.

Comment: Thanks good point, however before this code executes, an isset() was used on the onLoad() of the index.php on first site visit and set the 'loginStatus' session variable.   The proof of it is that the first 'Testing' alert box above appears fine, and correctly indicates that the 'loginStatus' got set to 'false'.

Comment: I see ... I'm more just trying to make a point about referencing PHP variables than anything.

Comment: thanks, I very much appreciate your effort -- I learned something from your comment, I've never used 'empty' before -- thanks for the effort.